# JQuery : Event on click or keydown without redundancies?

Tags: jquery, click, keydown, redundancy

What is the best way to do the same action if either a key press or a click is registered ?
I would like to avoid having redundancies and make the code shorter.

Thank you

Comment: what code have you so far?

Comment: Basically, at the moment, this is what I have: 

`$('.leftPlayer').click(function() {...});`
`$("body").keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 37) {...};
}); `

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) can take multiple event names separated by a space, and it will run the same handler for all:

```
$('#something').on('keypress click', function() {
    // run the same code
});
```

If you need more flexibility, for example with different conditions then you can create a function:

```
function myProcedure(e){
    if(e.type == "keydown"){
        console.log(e.keyCode);
    } elseif(e.type == "click"){
        console.log("clicked");
    }
}

$('.leftPlayer').click(myProcedure);
$('body').keydown(myProcedure);
```